# Using awk to filter a file based on conditions

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, bed

I have posted previosuly but I have not resolved the issue. I have two files one which includes 3 columns, called Chromosome and Gene_start Gene_end. There are approx 100 lines in this file. The first column contains a number (1-23) and Gene_start Gene_end contains a numeric value. If I filter for 4 in the first column or chromosome 4, my file looks like this:

```
>> cat gene_positions.txt
Chromosome Gene_start Gene_end 
4 25121627 25167204
4 170981373 171017850
4 37592422 37692998
4 84382094 84411290
```

I have another file with 14 columns, I am only interested in the first two columns of this file. CHROM and POS:

```
>> cat gwas_results.txt
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  L95 U95 T_STAT  P
1   22004791    1:54712:T:TTTTC T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00256645 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818212  0.934799
1   22105000    1:54712:T:TC    T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00259875 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818216  0.94799
1   825410  rs13303179:825410:G:A   G   A   G   ADD 1597    -0.017462   0.0235123   -0.0635454  0.0286213   -0.742676   0.457788
```

If the first column from file 1 matches exactly to the first column of the second file as well as the second column of gwas_results.txt called POS falls within the range of the second and third column of file 1 (Gene_start Gene_end) for that particular line, then to print the line in the lookup_output.txt. Essentially, the gene_positions is a lookup file, with three columns and the first is a number that should match the first column of the gwas_results.txt, next if the POS in gwas_results.txt falls within the range of the Gene_start Gene_end from the first file, I want the line from gwas_results.txt to be printed.

I am using the following awk command as was suggested before:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=genelookup
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=16gb
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --export=NONE

cd /data/genome/hj/GWAS_results 

awk '
NR == FNR {
   start[$1] = $2
   end[$1] = $3
   next
}
$1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $3 <= end[$1]
' gene_positions.txt gwas_results.txt > lookup_output.txt
```

What I get are some positions outside the range in my lookup_output.txt

```
4   84529777    4:84529777:ACGTG:A  ACGTG   A   ACGTG   ADD 1635    0.00986994  0.0253137   -0.039744   0.0594839   0.389905    0.696658
4   85092377    4:84392377:G:T  G   T   T   ADD 1635    -0.00336762 0.0415539   -0.0848117  0.0780765   -0.0810422  0.935418
```

For example 84529777 is outside the range from the gene_positions file (4 84382094 84411290). I need the lookup to be line to line basis. E.g. scans the file for chromosome 4 and positions within 84382094 84411290 range. If found print.

I also get

```
4   37700998    4:84392377:G:T  G   T   A   ADD 1635    -0.0033 0.047539    -0.0847 0.0780765   -0.08   0.93
```

But this is outside the range (4 37592422 37692998) from the gene positions.

I really should be seeing

```
4   25121630    4:84392377:G:T  G   T   T   ADD 1635    -0.00336762 0.0415539   -0.0848117  0.0780765   -0.0810422  0.935418
4   25131627    4:84392378:A:T  A   T   T   ADD 1635    -0.00336762 0.0415539   -0.0848117  0.0780765   -0.0810422  0.935418
4   170981374   4:84415536:CA:C CA  C   C   ADD 1635    -0.0359081  0.0576552   -0.14891    0.0770941   -0.622807   0.533499
4   171017750   4:84415882:AAACATG:A    AAACATG A   A   ADD 1635    -0.00552875 0.0522986   -0.108032   0.0969745   -0.105715   0.915821
4   37492998    4:84454092:T:TTATATATG  T   TTATATATG   TTATATATG   ADD 1635    0.0148902   0.0442058   -0.0717516  0.101532    0.336838    0.736283
4   37592998    4:84458776:G:GTA    G   GTA GTA ADD 1635    -0.000157512    0.0252463   

etc...
```

BECAUSE...they second column called POS is all within the range of the positions in the gene_positions.txt file, providing it is chromosome 4. In other words, the first column of 'gwas_results.txt' ($1) matches a value in the first column of 'gene_positions.txt' and if this is true, then the second column of 'gwas_results.txt' ($2) falls within the range defined by the second and third columns of 'gene_positions.txt' (Gene_start and Gene_end) for the particular chromosome.

Comment: Can you change condition part to `$1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $2 <= end[$1]` (it was corrected in my answer as well)

Comment: please update the question's sample data to provide rows from both files that *a)`* match and *b)* do not match; right now we have chrom=1 in one file and chrom=4 in another file, so there's no way any of those rows are going to 'match', right? also insure the expected output matches the provided inputs ... right now we have 4x chrom=4 rows in the input but 6x chrom=4 rows in the output; we should be able to take your sample inputs and generate the desired output ... right now that's not possible since the inputs can't be matched, an the expected output does not match with the provided inputs

Comment: Thanks it worked with your update anubhava. I want to understand how this works. We are storing file columns from file 1 into start[$1]  and end[$2] and chromosome column 1 is just $1. 
NR == FNR {
   chromosome[$1];
   start[$1] = $2;
   end[$1] = $3;
   next
}
$1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $2 <= end[$1]. I am not sure what $1 in start  is but after than we are saying $2 from gwas_results must be greater or equal to start position and smaller than end position from file 1. How does awk know it needs to do this line by line?

Comment: `NR == FNR { ... }` block of code is for the first file in argument so all the `$1, $2, $3` are from 1st file only. However `$1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $2 <= end[$1]` block is executed for 2nd file and all the `$1, $2, $3` are from 2nd file only.

Comment: this is a job for bedtools intersect. Just convert the second file to bed `awk -F '\t' '{printf("%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n",$1,int($2)-1,$2,$0);}'` , sort both files and use `bedtools intersect`